# Authentication causing duplicate page rendering

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

Let me try to explain this in english :).

I'm having trouble with the authentication in Mvc. I use my layout page to login and to show the other partial views with content.
I decorated the login methods with `<AllowAnonymous()> _` to let people login into the page and in my webConfig i have the following entry:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

What's happening is when the session expires, the partial view renders the entire page again and i get the entire page twice (one inside the content).

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thks for the answer, but i solved my problem with the following post :
[C# MVC: How to override configured authentication redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519393/c-sharp-mvc-how-to-override-configured-authentication-redirect)

Answer (score 1):

You may checkout the [following article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx)  from Phil Haack which illustrates a nice technique allowing you to prevent the forms authentication module to automatically redirect to the LogOn page but return 401 status code. This could be done conditionally only for AJAX requests. And since the server now returns 401 status code you could detect it on your client side AJAX call and act accordingly.